# How to configure a wp-config.php file outside the rest of the wordpress files?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ecs

I got my wordpress files in **/var/www/html/** but I would like my **wp-config.php** file to be in a mounted volume in **/app/config/** for security reasons.

I cannot mount the volume directly like this **/app/config/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php** because I'm mounting it via AWS ECS and for some reasons I only can mount directories...

Which wordpress files should I modify to make it search **wp-config.php** in **/app/config/** ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a `wp-config.php` file in `/var/www/html` that simply contains nothing but the following:

```
<?php
include(‘/app/config/wp-config.php’);
?>
```